# Checking if string contains valid Python code

Tags: python

I am writing some sort of simple web-interpreter for vk.com . I look for messages, check if they are valid Python code, and then I want to execute that code, and return any `stdout` to code sender. I have implemented anything but code checker.

```
import ast

def is_valid(code): 
    try:
        ast.parse(code)
    except SyntaxError:
        print('Input isnt code.')
        return False
    print('Code is ok.')
    return True
```

`is_valid()` always return `True` regardless of what comes in. Im really confused...

Comment: Can you give an example of non-code that returns `True`.

Comment: >>> is_valid('test')
    Code is ok.
    True

Comment: That's valid code - an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, the difference between a runtime error and a parser error is significant in your case and example. The statement:

```
test
```

is *valid* code. Even though this statement will throw a `NameError` when the Python VM executes the code, the parser will not know that it actually wasn't assigned a value before the statement is parsed, so that's why it's a runtime error, and not a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! Ill fix it by throwing `NameError` then

Comment: @MaxLunar you can't throw a NameError, because how would you know that the user's code is using a variable that wasn't assigned a value?

Comment: @MaxLunar I think you have a misunderstanding here. Is `x + 1` valid code?

Comment: Hm, If i send message that tell user that his variable wasnt defined yet if NameError is raised...

Comment: @MaxLunar Why? What if `x` is not defined? Or if `x` is a string?

Comment: It's valid because it follows the rules of Python syntax. Some languages, like C, won't compile if you don't define all your variables (for example), but Python is not one of those languages. For all it knows, you will define `x` in some other way before that code runs.